# SSH client connection not working to remote servers not working

Tags: ssh, openssh

I am unable to connect to other machines from one of my servers.

Here is the verbose output (IP, domain, port are masked. OpenSSH version info removed):

```
$ ssh -vvv user@example.com -p yyyy
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to example.com [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] port yyyy.
ssh: connect to host example.com port yyyy: Connection timed out
```

What I originally doing was trying to clone one of our git repo. Then I figured out that no SSH connection is going out from this system.

I tried ssh connection to different servers. And all those servers are perfectly connectible from my local machine. So it means, problem is with this specific system.

Do there any steps to diagnose  why SSH connections are not going out from a system? Is there any specific configuration that prevent making SSH connection to remote machines?

I examined /etc/ssh/ssh_configure and it only have these configurations active:

```
Host *
        GSSAPIAuthentication yes
# If this option is set to yes then remote X11 clients will have full access
# to the original X11 display. As virtually no X11 client supports the untrusted
# mode correctly we set this to yes.
        ForwardX11Trusted yes
# Send locale-related environment variables
        SendEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES 
        SendEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT 
        SendEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
        SendEnv XMODIFIERS
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Are you using the same client machine for all tests? That is, you have a single host that can connect to many other machines, except for `example.com`? I ask because you claim that "no SSH connection is going out from this system." Either that is wrong, or you are testing with multiple client machines.

Comment: `ssh -vvv` output is usually several pages. You really only removed a version string? And why remove it? I get why you remote host and site info, but why do you care if we know what version of OpenSSH you are using? It might help to know.

Comment: What do you get if you run `tshark -i eth0 host example.com and port 22` in a separate window? You need to do that as `root`, and `eth0` may need to change for your particular setup; use the interface name that you expect the SSH connection to use. If you don't have Wireshark installed, you might have `tcpdump`, which accepts the same command line format; it's just a bit more difficult to read its output.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a non-standard port, i.e. not 22? Are your other tests to other systems also to that same (non-22) port?